# Use of gulp+browserify+babalify for ES6 code referenced from external javascript.

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I have been working on a side project to our main project using es6 classes, import and export.  The main code uses Angular 1 (i.e. AngularJS)

I have followed advice here and elsewhere on using browsify and babelify and have almost gotten it working but am stuck on what i hope is the last step.  I cannot reference my library from the main code.

We use gulp so I need to fit it into that framework.  I have come up with the following to create the library:

```
function cliCompile() {
    console.log('Compiling client-server...');
    return browserify({
        entries: 'cli/main.js',
        debug: true,
        require: './cli/main.js',
        transform: [babelify]})
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('cli.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/compiled'));
}
```

The require generated by this is unique to my computer (full path) so I clearly need to use an alias.  However, it appears aliasing doesn't work well with the above, or I don't know the correct format.  Changing the requre line to

```
require: 'cli/main.js:CSMain"
```

did not work as it treated the full thing quoted string as the filename/module.

Is there a way to rewrite this so it would work and have an alias I can refer to in the main angular code?  Note that the line to reference the function I gave above is:

```
gulp.task('cli', cliCompile);
```

Comment: Where is this library located? If it is an `npm` dependency you usually just use the library name. If not, you'll need some sort of relative path.

Comment: The library and the main code are to be separate js files to be copied to the server.  npm got us the tools like gulp but have nothing to do with the server which is independent of all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aliasing does get around this.  However it appears you cannot specify require options when you pass in require as part of the initial parameters.

Instead call .require as follows:

```
gulp.task('cli', cliCompile);
....
function cliCompile() {
    console.log('Compiling client-server...');

    var b = browserify({
        entries: 'cli/main.js',
        debug: true,
        transform: [babelify]});
    b.require('./cli/main.js', {expose: 'cli'});
    return b.bundle()
        .pipe(source('cli.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/compiled'));
}
```

It is also possible to put the require in the list:

```
return browserify({
        entries: 'cli/main.js',
        debug: true,
        transform: [babelify]})
            .require('./cli/main.js', {expose: 'cli'})
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source('cli.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/compiled'));
```